# RTP Stream is Visible from Internal IP but not from Public IP

Tags: networking, ip, rtp

I'm trying to stream an RTP stream to a port on an external ip.

When I attempt to load the stream using the internal ip on the pc itself, everything works.

When instead I try to stream using the external ip (even though I'm streaming to it), I cannot connect at all.

What troubleshooting should I be aware of, especially considering that we're using RTP?

So far we have done the following:

1. Opened the firewall and respective ports used (UDP).
2. We streamed the same stream over HTTP
3. On the server itself, I can stream only using the internal ip, but not the external ip, even when I'm using the external ip as the address I want to stream to.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that RTP cannot be sent over the internet (at least not using VLC).

When I changed the protocol to RTSP, everything worked out ok.

Answer (score 1):

- Check that the server process is bound to the external IP address.
- Check that the server system's firewall isn't blocking access.
- Check that upstream systems aren't blocking access.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. @lain

Firewalls are down and we've checked that the port is open (on UDP).

We've managed to stream over HTTP on the same port.

I'm afraid that I don't understand the first point.

Comment: What is supposed to receive the RTP stream? Is it listening on the port and IP you are sending to on the remote machine?

Comment: The RTP stream should be accessed by anyone online.  The IP I'm sending to is the server hosting the RTP stream.  Is this correct?